# How to read from stdin until EOF

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I need a simple solution for reading this input

```
==*====*====
===@===
**@@@==*@@=*@*=
*=*=*=*=*=*=
==*@===*=*@=
```

I tried with this but it doesn't end whenever the input is read, however the string value is stored. I would need to add code after reading so that's why while should end and I can move on with my code.

```
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
while(true){
    if (!sc.hasNextLine()) {
        break;
    }
    String sor=sc.nextLine();
}
```

I appreciate the help in advance, please make me understand why the while doesn't break.

Comment: This may sound stupid but are you "Pressing Enter" after the last input ?

Comment: Here you input stream is System.in which is kind of infinite input stream. What you need to do is don't use hasNextLine. Rather send some control sequence like CTRL + D or some string matching like "STOP" or "END" after the end of input and use to get out of loop.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however i am looking for something that doesn't require an input after the original lines. Also, yes I'm pressing enter :D.

Comment: If you give file stream as input to your scanner, your code will work fine.

Comment: It seems to work just fine. Btw, why not use `while(sc.hasNextLine())` instead of the `while(true)` with if-statement and `break`? [Here in an online compiler to see the while-loop stops and you have the list of lines.](https://ideone.com/OFZCo0)

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be the only possible solution for my problem.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you need not specify the if() here as its already getting verified in while().
If input is being read from a file it should work absolutely fine. If you are reading it from some other input stream, it should terminate the line.

```
 Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    while(sc.hasNextLine()){
        String sor=sc.nextLine();
    }
```